# How to handle null exception when converting from object to string?

Tags: c#, .net, null

Just curious:

These lines throw `Invalid Cast Exception`: 
`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.`

```
 Object obj = new object();
 obj = 20.09089;
 string value = (string)obj;
```

I receive the `obj` value from a `library`.

How to simply convert to `string` when we don't know the type of `object` while enumerating?

Comment: In addition to the answers, note that there's a difference between `(string)obj` and `obj.ToString()`...

Comment: Simply use `string value = obj.ToString();`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - In this case, yes. But since there is "null exception" in the title, one might also have to take into account that `obj` could be `null`.

Comment: which exception is it, a NullReference or Invalid Cast?  If `obj` is returned from a lib function, each exception could result under different circumstances

Comment: @Corak I assume it was by mistake. Above code shouldn't throw NRE even when `obj` is null.

Comment: Btw. if you don't know the *exact* type, but are certain, that it can only be one of a handfull of known types, you could check that with [is/as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc488006.aspx). `if (obj is double) { \\ do double stuff }`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Huh? `obj.ToString()` *will* throw if `obj` is `null`.

Comment: @Corak I mean Op's code, not my code. Sorry for the confusion. `(string)obj;` won't throw. It will work as expected and so I assume OP never got NRE.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Ah, yes. `(string)null` won't throw. But `(string)anythingButStringOrNullOrWithACastingOperator` will. So the safest way would be the one yackov showed.

Comment: @Corak: Just trying to understand. In yackov's answer -> Shouldn't we use `Convert.ToString()` instead of `.ToString()` method since it handles `null` values too

Comment: `Convert.ToString()` does the same thing in the end. But it also checks if the given object implements `IConvertible` or `IFormattable` beforehand (and calls the more appropriate `ToString` methods if they do). So if you want those checks, or at least can live with them, then go for it. Yackov just showed the way with possibly the smallest footprint while still being safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that is why every object in .net has the ToString() method (inherited from Object)

```
string str = (obj == null) ? string.Empty : obj.ToString();
```

Comment: Great answer. BTW, I am now using `Convert.ToString()` instead of  `.ToString()` since the former can handle null values too :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an [boxing / unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) issue.

`20.09089` is a [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) by default. When you wanna unbox a primitive type from `object`, you need to unbox it the **original type first**.

```
Object obj = new object();
obj = 20.09089;
string value = ((double)obj).ToString();
```

or simplify;

```
Object obj = new object();
obj = 20.09089;
string value = obj.ToString();
```

Comment: That is superfluous, simply use `obj.ToString`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That's right. I just want to point why OP _can't_ cast directly to string as `(string)obj` in my answer instead of how to get it's string representation. But I added to my answer. Thanks.